# PrimeFaces f:setPropertyAction with dataTable works only after a row is selected

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Here is my Problem:

- Backing bean is `@SessionScoped`
- I have a `p:dataTable` with *selectionMode* set to single and *selection* `#{bean.selectedCar}`
- first column in the table is a commandLink that *updates* a dialog :detailDialog, *oncomplete* shows the dialog and has an *actionListener* that hast to clear some property in the bean
- `f:setPropertyListener` has a value `#{item}` and target `#{bean.selectedCar}`

I want that the user is able to click the link and the dialog will display the information for the object on the row, but it works only if a row in the dataTable was selected first. If no row was selected and the user clicks on the commandLink NULL is passed to the `bean.selectedCar` and the page hangs.

As a workaround I would like at least to be able to preselect the first row in the dataTable and hopefully this will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-use your `f:setPropertyListener` in your command link:

```
<p:commandLink value="show" 
               actionListener="#{bean.doSomething}" 
               oncomplete="dialog.show()">
    <f:setPropertyListener value="#{item}" target="#{bean.selectedCar}"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

alternatively (since we are iterating through a dataTable) you can pass the current `#{item}` object to your `<p:commandLink.../>`:

```
<p:commandLink value="Show" 
               action="#{bean.selectThisCar(item)}" 
               oncomplete="dialog.show()"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @akoskm for your answer. The first variant was that what I used for the button. My problem was that (as the second option) this method conflicted with the selection option in the dataTable. Removing the `selection="#{bean.selectedCar}"` from the `p:dateTable` parameters was the salution of my problem. Thanks for the help.